# custom colors on softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i have this keyboard:
[image]

i think the keyboard come from a tutorial of a basic keyboard.

I want to change the background for every key:

Here i put every key:

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"  
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height">

<Row>
    <Key android:codes="113" android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
    <Key android:codes="119" android:keyLabel="w"/>
    <Key android:codes="101" android:keyLabel="e"/>
    <Key android:codes="114" android:keyLabel="r"/>
    <Key android:codes="116" android:keyLabel="t"/>
    <Key android:codes="121" android:keyLabel="y"/>
    <Key android:codes="117" android:keyLabel="u"/>
    <Key android:codes="105" android:keyLabel="i"/>
    <Key android:codes="111" android:keyLabel="o"/>
    <Key android:codes="112" android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
</Row>
```

I don't know if i can change the style from there

**Update**
My KeyboardView:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/message_bg"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/preview">
</android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView>
```

Keyboard.java

```
    public void onInitializeInterface() {

    qwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);

    symbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols);

    symbolsShiftedKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_shift);

    fillKeyboard = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fill_keyboard, null);

    dialogAccounts = new Builder(this);

    dialogAllAccounts = new Builder(this);

    usersTextView = (Button) fillKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.userTextView);

    noCredentials = (Button) fillKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.noCredentials);

} 

/**
 * Select the view in the keyboard depending of the Globals.isLoged
 */
@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {

    Globals.isKeyboard = true;

    Globals.tokenKeyboard = this.getWindow().getWindow().getAttributes().token;

    database = new PwdDatabaseHelper(this);
    loginKeyboard = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.log_keyboard, null);

    if (!Globals.isLoged) {

        myMasterPassword = (EditText) loginKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.masterPasswordKeyboard);

        currentKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) loginKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);

        currentKeyboardView.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);

        currentKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

        return loginKeyboard;
    } else {

        if (fillUsersAndPass() != 0) {
            currentKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) fillKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
            currentKeyboardView.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);
            currentKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            noCredentials.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            usersTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            return fillKeyboard;
        } else {

            currentKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) fillKeyboard.findViewById(R.id.keyboardView);
            noCredentials.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            currentKeyboardView.setKeyboard(qwertyKeyboard);
            currentKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
            return fillKeyboard;
        }

    }
}
```

**Update 2**

keyboard.xml

```css
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:color="#8e44ad"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:color="#e67e22"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:color="#e74c3c"/>  <!--default -->

</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the key backgrounds from your KeyboardView. In your xml, add this to your KeyboardView:

```
android:keyBackground="@drawable/yourDrawable"
android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/yourLayout"
```

Where yourDrawable is a drawable file (It can't be an image), and yourLayout is a layout with the parent view set as a TextView.

For more info: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html

**Edit:**

As google docs say:

> **android:keyBackground**
>
> Image for the key. This image needs to be a StateListDrawable, with the following possible states: normal, pressed, checkable, checkable+pressed, checkable+checked, checkable+checked+pressed.

So you will have to create a drawable shape file and not an image.

Example:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="#8e44ad" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="#e67e22" /> <!-- focused -->

    <item
        android:color="#e74c3c" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.html#attr_android:keyBackground

Comment: i have the keyPreviewLayout and it works but the keyBackground dont, still show the same background

Comment: What did you write there as your drawable? An image or shape file?

Comment: It can be any of them. What did you write?

Comment: android:keyBackground="@drawable/message_bg", it's an gray image

Comment: That should work. Can you post your whole code regarding your keyboard please?

Comment: That seems weird. Maybe you should try to make a drawable shape file instead of an image, I have never tested it with an image. I used it as a drawable shape file with state_focused, state_pressed. So try that if you can, then tell me.

Comment: @portal47 Please check my updated answer. Unfortunately, you can't use an image unless you put that image as a drawable in another drawable shape file. So it's a drawable inside another drawable file. If you need more help, tell me.

Comment: i make something like you say but dont works, you can check my update 2